# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable in send_mail?

Tags: python

I'm trying to send an email using Python, but when I run this code, I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

The error is apparently on this line:

```
 email = list(cursor.fetchone())
```

What's the issue here, and how might I go about fixing this?

```py
    @app.route('/send_mail', methods = ['POST'])
    def send_mail():
      test_append = str(request.form['folder_name'])
      teacher_name = str(session.get('user'))
      excel_dir = APP_ROOT + "/excel/" + test_append + "/" + teacher_name + "/"
      excel_date = request.form['fname']
      time = request.form['ftime']
      time = time[: 2]
      final_send = glob(excel_dir + "/" + excel_date + "@" + time + "*.xlsx")[0]
      print(final_send)
      df = pd.read_excel(final_send)
      roll_id = list(df['Roll Id'])
      print(type(roll_id))
      print(roll_id)
      cursor = conn.cursor()
      for i in range(len(roll_id)):
        cursor.execute("SELECT student_email,parent_email from student_login where binary roll_id=%s", [roll_id[i]])
        email = list(cursor.fetchone())
        print(type(email[1]))
        print(email[0])
        print(email[1])
        msg = Message('Auto Generated', recipients = [email[0], email[1]])
        msg.body = "Hi.. " + roll_id[i] + " is present for the lecture of " + "Prof. " + str(teacher_name.split('.', 1)[0]) + ", which is held on " + excel_date + "@" + time + "hrs"
        msg.html = "Hi.. " + roll_id[i] + " is present for the lecture of " + "Prof. " + str(teacher_name.split('.', 1)[0]) + ", which is held on " + excel_date + "@" + time + "hrs"
        mail.send(msg)
      return "<h1>mail sent<h1>"
```

Comment: `cursor.fetchone()` returns a single row, why do you want to turn it into a `list`?

Comment: Please try to reduce this to a [mre].

Comment: @Thomas so the code will be email = cursor.fetchone( ) right?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the result set of

```
cursor.execute("SELECT student_email,parent_email from student_login where binary roll_id=%s", [roll_id[i]])
```

It might be empty.

Comment: ok i had rechecked the database and my database are wrong. So right now, i had another error on line print(type(email[1])). The output of error is 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. How to fix?